# How to reconcile ede-minor-mode and org mode C-c . keybindings?

Tags: org-mode

I have been able to setup `CEDET` and `ede` for use as a development environment, but I also am trying to use org mode.
In my cedet configuration, I have `(global-ede-mode t)`.  When I open a .org file and try to timestamp something,<kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> is overridden by ede-minor-mode <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> letter functions.
I can't figure out a way to disable ede mode in org-mode buffers, so to timestamp anything, I have to `M-x org-time-stamp`, instead of <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>.
All my searches have not shown me a concrete way to do this.  Anyone have an answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least a couple of ways of fixing this:

1. Globally change `ede`'s keybindings from `C-c .` to something else.

   For example, if you want to use `C-c e` instead of `C-c .`
   everywhere, you can add this to your init file to the section
   where you configure `ede`:

   ```
   (with-eval-after-load 'ede
     (define-key ede-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c e")
       (lookup-key ede-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c .")))
     (define-key ede-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c .") nil))
   ```
2. Deactivate `ede` in Org mode buffers.

   ```
   (defun deactivate-ede-in-org-buffers ()
     (when (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
       (ede-minor-mode -1)))

   (add-hook 'find-file-hook #'deactivate-ede-in-org-buffers t)
   ```

EDIT: This answer used to have another suggested solution that boiled down to:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-c .") #'org-time-stamp)
```

That doesn't work! I misremembered the priorities of the various keymaps: I thought the local one takes precedence over minor modes, but it's the other way around, as [explained in the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html).

Comment: I tried (2) both in the file where I set global-ede-mode and in the file where I configure org mode.  It doesn't seem to work.  When I open a .org file, C-c . F1 still shows ede being mapped.  But (1) worked nicely.  I would ultimatley like to figure out how to shut down EDE when in org-mode (don't see why I would need that there), but that works for now.  Thanks!

Comment: @tenspd137 I thought the local keymap took precedence over minor mode keymaps, but it doesn't. I've removed the incorrect method and added a way to disable `ede` in Org mode buffers.

Comment: Thanks again for your help - I'll give that a shot as well when I get a chance.  Much appreciated.  Kind of a new user (slowly) figuring things out.